# Typescript Interface Add Unknown Dynamic variables

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'd like to define a interface that has some known variables and some other dynamic.

Let's assume this definition of interface:

```
export interface ApplicationData {
      applicant?: ApplicantData;
      application_unit?: ApplicationUnit;
      interested_people_count?: number | undefined;
}
```

How would I define that in this interface could also be:

```
interested_person_1: InterestedPerson;
interested_person_3: InterestedPerson;
expenses_1q_2023: Expenses;
expenses_3q_2022: Expenses;
```

So I do not know in advance how many these variables will be there, only what I know is that if it starts with 'interested_person_' then it is InterestedPerson interface and if it starts with 'expenses_' then it is Expenses interface.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHpAdgZwsqBeKBvAsAKCikQEMBbCALigHIIEIU0aBuAgXzfwNEigElEwCACc0wgCYAFUcgD2iTDgJFSFajUgj5iVhy49w0AOKNRASwDGAFSNK8hKAG041AAbmho8RAkB9LR0-ABJsZGARTwBzdjcAXWpBYTFw3xltBS4iF3d6JFRkELCI6NiE2AYmZC5OAgJLBXCoEmpTRAsbOywHIk9kn39AhT8ARmoeomJyKloh3QAaFSh2Rcc8xgLR8aXVaY11qppVohX9AiA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame Yeah, it works! Great :-) Could you please explain it?

Comment: It uses template strings to define index signatures that match certain patterns (in this case, the two prefixes).

Comment: On the line of actual usage: Where does this data come from? Why a whole lot of properties and not just two with arrays and/or Maps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to define two [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), one for interested persons and the other one for expenses. To define the keys we are going to use [template strings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html).

Example:

```
type StartsWithInterest = `interest_${string}`
```

This type will handle all strings that start with `interest_` and the rest of it doesn't matter for the compiler:

```
const ok: StartsWithInterest = 'interest_correct'
const notOk: StartsWithInterest = 'incorrect' //expected error
```

We can apply the template string to our index signatures that will give us the desired result:

```
type GenericType = {
  [x: `interested_person_${string}`]: InterestedPerson;
  [x: `expenses_${string}`]: Expenses;
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHpAdgZwsqBeKBvAsAKCikQEMBbCALigHIIEIU0aBuAgXzfwNEigElEwCACc0wgCYAFUcgD2iTDgJFSFajUgj5iVhy49w0AOKNRASwDGAFSNK8hKAG041AAbmho8RAkB9LR0-ABJsZGARTwBzdjcAXWpBYTFw3xltBS4iF3d6JFRkELCI6NiE2AYmZC5OAgJLBXCoEmpTRAsbOywHIk9kn39AhT8ARmoeomJyKloh3QAaFSh2Rcc8xgLR8aXVaY11qppVohX9AiA)